# Setting the default Local folder in Coda?

Tags: macos, coda

I just started using Coda and the local folder defaults to my home directory when I open the program. Is there a way to set the default local folder in Coda to my web development folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. The Panic folks have excellent support, there might be a hidden preference for this, but I didn't find anything.

Coda is built around Sites/Projects, and only those allow you to define a local directory.

As a workaround, you can create  "Sites" that **only** specifiy the `Local Root`. When you open one of these Sites after startup, the only thing that happens is that the local directory gets changed.

[image: Screenshot of Sites editor]

Comment: I figured that this was my only option. Thanks!

Comment: It seems to use the value set for NFSHomeDirectory, although changing that would cause a number of problems in most cases. In addition to Daniel Beck's solution I also created link named "_LocalServer" in my home directory so I can navigate there quickly either way.